# Start DropWizard server with command line : i want to use maven jar plugin only

Tags: java, rest, maven, plugins, dropwizard

I have a basic dropwizard web application (REST service). I want to execute the server using maven-jar-plugin (first pom.xml below) and not maven shade plugin which which is advised by the editor (second pom.xml below). It is just an advise from dropwizard so i think that it is not mandatory. Am i wrong ?

The commande line to execute that basic dropwizard web application is :

> java -jar target/MavenSimpleArtifact-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  server
> introduction-config.yml

However, when i run that CLI command to start the application, what happens is :

- it does not find main class in manifest file !
- but main class IS INDICATED in manifest file !

The screen shot below shows that main class cannot be loaded with the pom.xml i want to use
[image]

The screen shot below shows that Manifest file has the awaited information with the pom.xml i want to use:
[image]

1. Here is the pom.xml i want to use and that CLI command generates the error :

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>MavenSimpleGroupe</groupId>
   <artifactId>MavenSimpleArtifact</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
       <mainclass>com.dropwizard.introduction.IntroductionApplication</mainclass>
       <dropwizard.version>2.0.0</dropwizard.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
           <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>                          
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. And Here is the pom.xml that runs without a problem

It is using "maven shade plugin" but that i don't want to use it !!

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MavenSimpleGroupe</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenSimpleArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainclass>com.dropwizard.introduction.IntroductionApplication</mainclass>
    <dropwizard.version>2.0.0</dropwizard.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So can someone help me understand what is going on.

Here is the github repository link to the application [HERE](https://github.com/userInterview/LoizDropWizard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i want to use "maven-jar-plugin" i have to use "maven-dependency-plugin".
This way it works. It works because Maven copies the dependant jars in the target folder, in a folder name "dependency".

Before running the application :

- copy paste that pom.xml below
- Update the maven project (right click in eclipse > update)
- in console, type : mvn clean package

Then, always in console, run the application with the following command line :

```
java -cp target/MavenSimpleArtifact-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/dependency/* com.dropwizard.introduction.IntroductionApplication
```

And here is the corresponding pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MavenSimpleGroupe</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenSimpleArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <dropwizard.version>2.0.0</dropwizard.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You could simplify your final command with help of classpathPrefix option of maven-jar-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your `java -jar ...` command fails because you don't have necessary classpath entries in runtime. You either need to collect all dependencies (we use `maven-assembly-plugin` for this) and pass them as `-classpath`/`-cp`/`CLASSPATH` argument or, as you already mentioned, use a shade plugin which incorporates all the needed dependencies inside resulting jar.

Comment: Hi ! Please give me a few moment so that i test this... i'll be back soon

Comment: You could also use `copy-dependencies` goal of `maven-dependency-plugin` to have your deps in target directory in combination with `addClasspath`/`classpathPrefix` of `maven-jar-plugin`

Comment: I know i can use "maven-assembly-plugin" but the point is that is want to keep "maven-jar-plugin". To do that i had to add the "maven-dependency-plugin" (see below). 
Idealy i would have wanted to use only "maven-jar-plugin".... Is that impossible ? Apache documentation is not clear about that.